# How to create new mobile phone contact from web using js ( Reactjs/NextJs)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create new contact using js. I only found documentation for getting all contacts from phone here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ContactsManager/select. Is there some lib to help me with this or is this only possible with react native ?

Comment: I also did some research about  DEEP LINKS. Can I somehow manipulate them to open my add new contact  screen?

Comment: Here is an article about how to do file downloads client-side: https://blog.logrocket.com/programmatic-file-downloads-in-the-browser-9a5186298d5c/

Here is an article about the vCard format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard

Comment: Thank you! You saved me from a sleepless night. Is there option to open directly contacts after this or this is the only way?